# I'm working with structures in scheme and need to extract and compare info inside of the structures

Tags: scheme, structure, racket

I'm making a structure in scheme to represent a person.  The structure contains the information for the persons name age and gender

```
(define-struct person (name height gender)
```

Thats my code for the structure.  Now i need to add a function that will categorize a person as tall or short based on their height.  I don't know exactly how to go about adding a condition to a structure to 1) Identify if the person is a male of female

```
(define-struct person (name height gender)
     (cond
        [gender? ('male)]
```

Something along those lines i assume?

2) I also have to find out how tall the person is and declare whether or not they are tall based on if their height (in inches) exceeds 69 for a woman and 72 inches for  men.  And then add a way to print out that persons name along with whether or not they are tall or short.

Comment: It may be better to define "person" as a class (rather than struct) where one can easily add different functions.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the condition to your function, rather than your structure?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little example. The example shows how to determine a whether a person is tall (I am leaving it as an exercise for you to figure out how to use different limits for men and women).

```
(define (tall? a-person) 
  (> (person-height a-person) 69)

(define (categorize a-person)
  (cond 
    [(tall? a-person) "tall"]
    [else             "short"]))

(categorize (person "Susan" 172 'female))
```